# My spark jobs are staying long time in accepted mode on aws EMR cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

My spark jobs are staying long time in accepted mode on aws EMR cluster. Previously my spark job staying less time in accepted mode now it is increased. Below are some of the configs that I am using let me know if any config need to investigate. Thanks.

```html
<property>
<name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-vcores</name>
<value>64</value>
<final>false</final>
<source>yarn-site.xml</source>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.disk-health-checker.min-free-space-per-disk-mb</name>
<value>0</value>
<final>false</final>
<source>yarn-default.xml</source>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.nodemanagers.heartbeat-interval-ms</name>
<value>250</value>
<final>false</final>
<source>yarn-site.xml</source>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-vcores</name>
<value>64</value>
<final>false</final>
<source>yarn-site.xml</source>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.client.application-client-protocol.poll-interval-ms</name>
<value>200</value>
<final>false</final>
<source>yarn-default.xml</source>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.timeline-service.client.retry-interval-ms</name>
<value>1000</value>
<final>false</final>
<source>yarn-default.xml</source>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.timeline-service.client.best-effort</name>
<value>false</value>
<final>false</final>
<source>yarn-default.xml</source>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.disk-health-checker.max-disk-utilization-per-disk-percentage</name>
<value>90.0</value>
<final>false</final>
<source>yarn-default.xml</source>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.cpu-vcores</name>
<value>1</value>
<final>false</final>
<source>mapred-default.xml</source>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.sharedcache.store.in-memory.check-period-mins</name>
<value>720</value>
<final>false</final>
<source>yarn-default.xml</source>
</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you job is spending a long time as accepted but this is a good indicator that there aren't free resources availble for your job to run.

If this is a shared cluster, talk to the administrator about getting more resources or getting them better allocated to you or what could be taking up the space.

If this is your cluster. Consider asking for less Memory for your jobs and you'll likely be able to get accepted faster. You may simply be asking for too much and yarn is having a hard time finding the space to allocate for you. (Or by a bigger cluster.)  It's a really common issue to over allocate driver/executor space, so try running with less and see what happens.

Try examining the resource manager to see what else is running that could be using up the space:
http://master-public-dns-name:8088/